# Why is resourceBundle output with strange symbols?

Tags: java, encoding, localization, resourcebundle

I try to internazionalize my web app and use Locale and ResourceBundle:

```
Locale locale = new Locale(language);
ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("i18n.messages", locale);
try {
    String message = messages.getString(key);
    pageContext.getOut().write(message);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

As a result the output is "Ôîðìà óïðàâëåíèÿ äëÿ àäìèíà". I don`t know what to do, please, help

Comment: My output word contains from Russian letters

Comment: The original text says "Форма управления для админа" in Windows-1251 encoding. You get strange characters because you display it in ISO-8859-1 encoding.

Comment: Please, can you write how to fix it using Windows-1251 encoding ?